# transform.localPosition = transform.localPosition causes GameObject to move?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having an issue moving a GameObject after I moved it into a parent with a Layout Element inside a Vertical Layout Group.

```
void Update()
{
    transform.localPosition = transform.localPosition;
}
```

This causes the object to move. I am confused about how assigning its current position can move it.

Comment: There is probably something else moving it. You mentioned it's inside a parent. Maybe the parent is the one moving?

Comment: Floating point error accumulation?